# How do you use void pointers to create a more general node structure?

Tags: c

I'm making an RPN Calculator that uses stacks and queues implemented as a linked list structure.  The problem is that the structure needs to be able to handle both symbols and numbers (including a data type I created for mixed numbers).  For this my teacher recommended using a void pointer type to store the data for each node as shown here:

```
typedef struct node {
    void* data;
    struct node* next;
} Node;
```

I'm not sure how to

1. dereference the pointer to use its address value or
2. add a node with different data types (int, char, or mixedNum)

Comment: You'd need another member in your `struct node` to store the type of the `data` referenced by your void pointer.

Comment: It would help if you showed the data type for mixed numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> For this my teacher recommended using a void pointer type to store the data for each node

Don't use `void*` unless you *really* need to, it's a bare untyped pointer to an arbitrary block of memory, and there are many pitfalls and potential bugs working that way.

> the structure needs to be able to handle both symbols and numbers (including a data type I created for mixed numbers).

That sounds like a job for a `union`, where you have another member tagging the type. Try something like this:

```
/* A tag to for the union type */
typedef enum
{
    Number,
    Symbol
} NodeType;

/* A Node can contain a symbol or numeric value */
typedef union
{
    char* symbol;
    float number;
} NodeData;

/* A linked list */
typedef struct Node
{
    NodeType type;
    NodeData data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
```

I suggest you create functions to do things like create a new symbol node, create a numeric node, setting the tag accordingly. You will probably want to `strdup` the symbol name so you own a copy of the string. A function to free a node (including freeing the string if it is of that type), etc, etc.

Comment: I think you're greatly overstating the case against `void *`, but I nevertheless agree that a union is a better choice for the situation the OP seems to be describing.

Comment: I'd put the `Node *` at the beginning, or at least before the `union`, so that you could (technically) put different types in the tree (for example, a `Number`-only node, or a `Symbol`-only node).  If you want to have *mutable* nodes, this won't work, but otherwise, it might be better for if you implement a smarter memory-management facility.

Answer (score 0):

As others, have already mentioned, a union is a better choice for this situation where you only need a few data types.

Although this is true, void* is more versatile and is a must if you want to create a more "general" linked list that can handle even custom types without you declaring it explicitly.

So, first of all, when implementing it with void*, it is quite common to use some typedefs that makes the code more readable. These are:

```
typedef void* Pointer
typedef struct node* ListNode
typedef ListNode* List
```

This will allow you to create a list simply by:

```
List list;
```

So, to answer to the question:

1) Let's assume you have a ListNode with an int* inside. To dereference it, you have to (int*)(ListNode->data). That casts Pointer to int*. If you want to get the actual value, you can always add an asterist before it.

2) The insert function would look something like this:

```
void insert(List list, Pointer data);
```

Since the data you give it is of type Pointer, you can put whatever you want there. For instance, if you want to put an int, you could do so by:

```
int a = 5;
insert(my_list, &a);
```